# Наиболее правильный и производительный способ вставки на страницу html через js

Tags: javascript, html

В JavaScript есть много способов вставки HTML на страницу, но часто возникают проблемы с безопасностью и производительностью.
Рекомендуют не использовать `innerHTML()`, но решения `createElement()` и т.д. кажутся слишком громоздкими, когда нужно вставить большой кусок кода. Ещё есть *templates*, но насколько это производительно и как правильно их организовать - в основном HTML файле или создавать отдельный(-е) для шаблонов?

Сейчас я использую `insertAdjacentHTML()` и мне кажется что нужно делать это более правильно. Подскажите, кой способ наиболее правильный и по-подробнее, как его применять?

Comment: А вы уверены что производительность вставки элементов в DOM это реально проблема? Ну и вообще кажется все давно перешли на react/vue/angular/ещё-один-фреймворк-который-появился-вчера

Comment: Ну и количество кода не должно вас пугать, если он по делу.

Comment: И что вам мешает проверить? Придумайте блок для вставки в html. Далее вставляйте блок в html, потом удаляйте и так 10000-100000  раз разными способами, замерьте время

Comment: `но решения createElement() и т.д. кажутся слишком громоздкими` для любого громоздкого кода можно написать универсальный объект-обертку и в коде работать уже с оберткой. ну а "какой вариант лучше" весьма ситуативный вопрос. где то create будет лучше, а где то и innerHTML сгодиться(хотя бы в качестве аргумента в холиваре :-D )